# window.onload does not work on mail client

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

I have this `script` written in my original webpage:

```
<script>
var marcoemail="aaaaaa";
   function pippo(){
      document.getElementById("marcoemailid").innerHTML=marcoemail;
   }
   window.onload = pippo;
</script>
```

But the mail client when sends the page to the email address, this `script` is not executed. I tried `body.onload`, `document.onload`, `window.onload`, but still it does not work.

Comment: Do you mean that this JS code is in an email? If so then this is by design. Email clients will block most, if not all, JS code from being executed for security reasons.

Comment: probably `window.onload = pippo();`

Comment: @AlexeyG tried that one as well. doesn't work

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no, this is the code which mail client will use to send the email to the email addresses. I also think that mail clients block <script>

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, all known email clients ignores `<script>` tags and inline js in multi-part email content. Also, some of the major email-clients such as Gmail webmail and, MSN webmail strips out the `<head>` tag all together so a general design rule is to keep everything (css) inline.

There is a good article bringing up scripts in email over at [Campaign monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/coding/).

If you can, you should try to strip the html content from script tags prior to sending it as an email as content including script tags will have an effect on the email´s spam score in most spam filters.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're going a wrong way...

Do this....

1 write a javascript code inside the page within `<script></script>` tag. here

```
<script>
var marcoemail = "aaaa";
function pippo(){
   document.getElementById("marcoemailid").innerHTML=marcoemail;
}
</script>
```

You should execute this function on body onload event then you should be modified body tag like this

```
<body onload ="pippo()">
```

Now it will working fine....

Comment: I tried all but still does not work, as @RoryMcCrossan suggested, it is blocked

Comment: Make sure javascript is enable in your browser....It has to work. but no any problems